# R if ggplot not last in function, it won't plot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I discovered that if ggplot *is* the last thing in a function, then calling the function will result in ggplot creating a plot as expected.

But if ggplot is not the last thing in a function -- say it is followed by an assignment (like x <- t) or a return statement (like return(x)) then ggplot will not create a plot.

What is the work around for this?

P.S. please throw in a comment explaining how to create an inline grey background used to indicate code :-)

Comment: surround your code with backticks (``) to create the `code` line

Comment: Use ` to surround the code.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by a *work around*. In R, the _last thing_ in a function is what is returned, unless you explicitly use `return(myObj)`. What do you want the function to return?

Comment: I think this is (a version of) FAQ 7.22, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314858/how-can-i-plot-multiple-residuals-plots-in-a-loop/24315262#24315262 ; put `print()` around your `ggplot` call ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `plot` for your `ggplot` object.

```
func1 <- function() {
  require(ggplot2)
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
}

func1()  # this creates plot


func2 <- function() {
  require(ggplot2)
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
  cat("hey\n")
}

func2()  # this does not create plot


func3 <- function() {
  require(ggplot2)
  plot(ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point())
  cat("hey\n")
}

func3()  # use plot to make sure your plot is displayed
```

By the way, `func1` creates plot not because `ggplot` is the last thing to do in the function.  It creates plot because the function returns the `ggplot` object and the code `func1()` invokes the `print` method of the object.
To see this, If you do `a <- func1()`, then the plot is not created, but stored in the `a` variable.

Note: You can use `print` insted.  `print` and `plot` are equivalent for the `ggplot` object.