# GGplot won't plot but base R will

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why does the following function draw a base R plot but not the GGplot equivalent?

(Base R call commented out)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

test <- function() {


  data <- data.frame("x"=1:10, "y"=1:20)

  mean <- mean(data$x)

  # Gplot, doesn't work
  data %>%
    ggplot( aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()

  # base R plot, does work
  #plot(data$x,  data$y)


  return(mean)

}

test()
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you do not explicitly return it, this works:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

test <- function() {


  data <- data.frame("x"=1:10, "y"=1:20)

  mean <- mean(data$x)

  # Gplot, doesn't work
  plot_gg <- data %>%
    ggplot( aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()

  # base R plot, does work
  #plot(data$x,  data$y)


  return(list(mean, plot_gg))

}

test()
```

If you want the plot to be shown without explicitly returning it, surround the plot with a `print` function like this (the reason you have to do this is because ggplot doesn't print when called inside a function, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314858/how-can-i-plot-multiple-residuals-plots-in-a-loop/24315262#24315262)):

```
test <- function() {


  data <- data.frame("x"=1:10, "y"=1:20)

  mean <- mean(data$x)

  # Gplot, doesn't work
  print(data %>%
    ggplot( aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point())

  # base R plot, does work
  #plot(data$x,  data$y)


  return(mean)

}

test()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike base `plot` `ggplot` doesn't print by default. You need to `print` it in the function if it isn't the last line of the function.

```
library(ggplot2)

test <- function() {

  data <- data.frame(x =1:10, y =1:20)
  mean <- mean(data$x)
  print(data %>%
          ggplot( aes(x=x, y=y)) +
          geom_line() +
          geom_point())

   return(mean)
}
```